# The jquery hide function

Tags: jquery, hide

I have a general query about the jquery hide function. I have looked around, and cant seem to find a straight answer. I want to know if the objects being hidden on page load are still loaded in and then hidden, or hidden and then load once a trigger is called. Also, if the the objects are loaded, are there any functions that will only load the hidden element once it is triggered?

Comment: It depends on where you call it.

Comment: Let me expand. I have a certain div that shows certain items. I have hidden items in the div on page load, and once the div is expanded with jquery with a button call,  the hidden elements are shown in an enlarged div. Are those items still being loaded in the background even thought they are hidden with hide() ?

Comment: if you do it on the document ready, it will funny enough first hide it after the DOM is loaded. And display:none(which is what the hide function basicly does) dosent restrict content from being loaded - only from being visible. So you should either do the filtering serverside, or add it with JS on load.

Comment: How would I go about creating a DIV that is only loaded once it is called within Jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `.hide()` on something inside `$(document).ready()`, then the element will be loaded as-is from the server, and then hidden once the page has completely loaded.

This can result in a 'flash' - seeing the element appear whilst the page is loading, then disappear once it has loaded. The best way to prevent this is to ensure it is rendered by the server with a style of `display:none;` if it is meant to be hidden initially.

Note that `.show()` and `.hide()` do not affect which elements exist in the DOM - i.e. which elements are loaded. Instead, they control the visibility of items once the page has loaded.

If you actually want to dynamically load in parts of the page, then you need to use jQuery's DOM manipulation methods to add new elements to the page in response to some event.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to the answers already given.

If you use jquery hide() to hide an element then the element will be displayed if the user has javascript turned off - because the hide() won't happen.  If the functionality or the need to show or hide is affected by the absence of javascript then its a good idea to cope with the scenario.  Some example CSS classes.

```
.hide-if-no-js {display:none;}
.show-if-no-js {display:block;}
.hide {display:none;}
```

Which you can then apply to the element, depending if you want to show or hide the element initially - regardless of whether javascript is available.

*Hide if js is unavailable, hide if js is available:*

```
<div id="aaa" class="hide-if-no-js">...</div>
```

*Show is js is unavailable, hide if js is available:*

```
<div id="aaa" class="show-if-no-js">...</div>
$("#aaa").removeClass("show-if-no-js").addClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, to hide something with jQuery, it has to be already loaded in the page, unless you create it from the javascript. What do you mean by 'loaded', added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

i think the content of the objects you hide with the `jQuery.hide` functions are always loaded. Because first your webpage will be loaded and after that the javascript will be executed. When you only want to content to be loaded when it is shown you should do an ajax call the load the content in or set the div to `display: none` initialy.